# How to install libraries such as OpenLayers with Bower?

Tags: openlayers, bower

I'm giving a try at [Bower](https://bower.io/) from the guys at Twitter, to manage my client-side dependencies.

But I'm facing a nasty problem: apart from a few big players ([jQuery](http://jquery.com/), and of course, [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) by Twitter), many libraries (most of them, actually) don't have a `component.json` file, and thus don't seem to support Bower.

This is the case with [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/), which is a big player, hence my surprise to find them not supporting Bower.

Am I missing something here? Or are there more common dependency managers that these big libraries do support at the moment?

Answer (score 8):

You can just to add the following as a dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
    "OpenLayers" : "http://openlayers.org/download/OpenLayers-2.12.zip"
}
```

and run `bower install` again.

**Update**
After Sindre remarks this conf breaks the `bower upgrade` you should rely on something like this : `bower install openlayers --save`

But be aware that if the artifacts you rely on it are not versionned in the repo, you'll have to build them in your dev workflow. It means having some more tools installed, and understanding them, etc.

Comment: Using a hardcoded path makes `bower upgrade` not work. Preferably use a git repo if possible.

Comment: Using git repo is the way to go, you're absolutely right. But what if artifacts are not versionned in the repo? There's no way we should include the building of our dependencies in our own build workflow. And that's why we see bare repo containing only the artifact (see repos for 'bowerized' angular modules).

Comment: That's a definite downside, but that's really up to the maintainers to fix not the package manager. You have multiple options available. Choose wisely.

Answer (score 5):

A component file is only required if the library has dependencies, otherwise the git tag is used.

You can do `bower install openlayers` since it's in the registry, otherwise you can use an url to a git repo or zip/tar file: `bower install git://github.com/openlayers/openlayers.git`.

Answer (score 4):

openlayers#2.13.1 is installable via Bower

Comment: Maybe it has been renamed to openlayers#release-2.13

Answer (score 2):

I had some 'fun' when it came to doing this,I included a referece to openLayers.js in my index.html  when I ran grunt serve, the reference to Openlayers.js was removed, and wiredep reported an injection problem.

The issue was caused by suppled version of OpenLays not having a 'main' token defined.

This is how you fix it.

In your html file, say

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

In the bower.json file (mines in the project root) say

```
{
 "name": "foobar",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "~3.2.0",
  "jquery-ui": "~1.11.2",
  "jquery": "~2.1.1",
  "openlayers": "1.0.0"
},
 "overrides": {
 "openlayers": {
       "main": "lib/OpenLayers.js"
  }
 } 
}
```

This defines the missing main token.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use npm for installing openlayers. https://www.npmjs.com/package/openlayers

```
npm install ol
```

Comment: Why should anybody use npm if the original question asked for a solution using bower?